# Keeping subset of row labels in pandas DataFrame based on second index

Tags: python, pandas

Given a DataFrame with a hierarchical index containing three levels (experiment, trial, slot) and a second DataFrame with a hierarchical index containing two levels (experiment, trial), how do I drop all the rows in the first DataFrame whose (experiment, trial) are not contained in the second dataframe?

Example data:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

df1_data = StringIO(u',experiment,trial,slot,token\n0,btn144a10_p_RDT,0,0,4.0\n1,btn144a10_p_RDT,0,1,14.0\n2,btn144a10_p_RDT,1,0,12.0\n3,btn144a10_p_RDT,1,1,14.0\n4,btn145a07_p_RDT,0,0,6.0\n5,btn145a07_p_RDT,0,1,19.0\n6,btn145a07_p_RDT,1,0,17.0\n7,btn145a07_p_RDT,1,1,13.0\n8,chn004b06_p_RDT,0,0,6.0\n9,chn004b06_p_RDT,0,1,8.0\n10,chn004b06_p_RDT,1,0,2.0\n11,chn004b06_p_RDT,1,1,5.0\n12,chn008a06_p_RDT,0,0,12.0\n13,chn008a06_p_RDT,0,1,14.0\n14,chn008a06_p_RDT,1,0,6.0\n15,chn008a06_p_RDT,1,1,4.0\n16,chn008b06_p_RDT,0,0,3.0\n17,chn008b06_p_RDT,0,1,13.0\n18,chn008b06_p_RDT,1,0,12.0\n19,chn008b06_p_RDT,1,1,19.0\n20,chn008c04_p_RDT,0,0,17.0\n21,chn008c04_p_RDT,0,1,2.0\n22,chn008c04_p_RDT,1,0,1.0\n23,chn008c04_p_RDT,1,1,6.0\n')
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(df1_data).set_index(['experiment', 'trial', 'slot'])

df2_data = StringIO(u',experiment,trial,target\n0,btn145a07_p_RDT,1,13\n1,chn004b06_p_RDT,1,9\n2,chn008a06_p_RDT,0,15\n3,chn008a06_p_RDT,1,15\n4,chn008b06_p_RDT,1,1\n5,chn008c04_p_RDT,1,12\n')
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(df2_data).set_index(['experiment', 'trial'])
```

The first dataframe looks like:

```
                            token
experiment      trial slot       
btn144a10_p_RDT 0     0         4
                      1        14
                1     0        12
                      1        14
btn145a07_p_RDT 0     0         6
                      1        19
                1     0        17
                      1        13
chn004b06_p_RDT 0     0         6
                      1         8
                1     0         2
                      1         5
chn008a06_p_RDT 0     0        12
                      1        14
                1     0         6
                      1         4
chn008b06_p_RDT 0     0         3
                      1        13
                1     0        12
                      1        19
chn008c04_p_RDT 0     0        17
                      1         2
                1     0         1
                      1         6
```

The second dataframe looks like:

```
                       target
experiment      trial        
btn145a07_p_RDT 1          13
chn004b06_p_RDT 1           9
chn008a06_p_RDT 0          15
                1          15
chn008b06_p_RDT 1           1
chn008c04_p_RDT 1          12
```

**The result I want**:

```
                            token
experiment      trial slot       
btn145a07_p_RDT 1     0        17
                      1        13
chn004b06_p_RDT 1     0         2
                      1         5
chn008a06_p_RDT 0     0        12
                      1        14
                1     0         6
                      1         4
chn008b06_p_RDT 1     0        12
                      1        19
chn008c04_p_RDT 1     0         1
                      1         6
```

Comment: Your code gives ``TypeError: initial_value must be unicode or None, not str``.

Comment: Hmm.  I retested by copy-and-pasting the code in the StackOverflow question and didn't get a type error.  I wonder if it's due to the Python version?  This is on Python 3 with Pandas 0.16.1.  I updated the code with the data strings as Unicode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What should work is

```
df1.loc[df2.index]
```

but multi indexing still has some problems. What does work is

```
df1.reset_index(2).loc[df2.index].set_index('slot', append=True)
```

which is a bit of a hack around this problem. Note that

```
df1.loc[df2.index[:1]]
```

gives garbage while

```
df.loc[df2.index[0]]
```

gives what you would expect. So passing multiple values from a m-level index to an n-level index where n > m > 2 doesn't work, though it should.

Comment: Marking this as correct since it includes an explanation for why the obvious approach doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it would by using [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html)

```
merged = pd.merge(
    df2.reset_index(),
    df1.reset_index(),
    left_on=['experiment', 'trial'],
    right_on=['experiment', 'trial'],
    how='left')
```

You just need to reindex `merged` to whatever you like (I could not tell exactly from the question).

Comment: Thanks!  This makes sense (I used a similar approach using the join method, but was thinking that somehow I could get the reindex method to do what I wanted).

Comment: Both answers are correct (posted by Amy Tavory and JoeCondron).  There are multiple ways to handle this since the most obvious way (`df1.loc[df2.index]`) isn't working in the current version of Pandas (0.16.1).